# Java Int Array returning all 0's

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, char, int

Hello all and thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I'm working on my Java homework (I understand the rules and I don't want you to do my homework, I'm just very stuck and am very confused so please to ban/yell at/poke me)

I have a class called Encryption. I'm calling this class in a Panel, which is being put into a Frame.

I need to read in user input and 'encrypt' that string with my own system using an Array.

I have read my book and searched for answers but I don't know why my INT array is returnign all O's. My Char array is returning the correct Char when I debug it, but my Int array is returning all 0's.

Here is what I have, any advice or suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Encryption {

private String finalEncryption;
int [] numArray = new int[25];
char[] charArray = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
char current;

//constructor
public Encryption(){

}

public String toString(){

    return finalEncryption;
}

public String setEncryption(String entry){

    String newEntry = entry.toUpperCase();

    //loop to go through each letter in the string
    for (int ch = 0; ch < newEntry.length(); ch++)
    {
        current = newEntry.charAt(ch);

        //loop to go through each letter in the alphabet
        for (int i=0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            if(current == charArray[i])
            {
                int finalEntry = numArray[i];
                System.out.println(finalEntry);

            }
            else if (current == numArray[i])
            {

            }

        }

        System.out.println(current);
    }

    return entry;
}

 }
```

Comment: it ll be 0's because you haven't gave data to it so.

Comment: To help you learn and not give you the answer I would ask you what data did you expect to get instead of 0 and why do you think that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An int array defaults to all zero's after you initialize it - this appears to be your case. Nowhere are you setting any values in the int array, you are only initializing it, and then reading it.

Comment: Ok. So one of the things I tried was to start with something like this  int [] numArray = {0,1,2,3}; but that also returned all 0's

Comment: If you do `int[] numArray = {0, 1, 2, 3 ...` all the way to 25, it should work.

Comment: Ok, I see what your saying. Thank you for your help. This was a huge help.

Comment: Just one note - if you are actually make an array of ints between 0-25, then your array is not very useful. You are putting in 5 for example, and getting back 5. You may as well simply use your index value right away. For example: `int finalEntry = i`

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Java not explicitly set to something, is initialized to a zero value.

int that is a 0.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) document.